# Failed to get app auth token TwitterApiException: HTTP request failed, Status: 403

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have integrate twitter kit with fabric plugin and also done the twitter initialisation with following code

```
 TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
    Fabric.with(getApplicationContext(), new Twitter(authConfig));
```

> i have also added callback url from fabric  dashboard  but still i am getting auth failed error below is my log cat

```
 E/Twitter: Failed to get app auth token
                                                           com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException: HTTP request failed, Status: 403
                                                               at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback.onResponse(Callback.java:42)
                                                               at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6209)
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Authorization completed with an error
                                                           com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Authorize failed.
                                                               at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.AuthHandler.handleOnActivityResult(AuthHandler.java:98)
                                                               at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterAuthClient.onActivityResult(TwitterAuthClient.java:161)
                                                               at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton.onActivityResult(TwitterLoginButton.java:131)
                                                               at in.crazyfingers.cyny.social_login.ActivitySocialSignIn.onActivityResult(ActivitySocialSignIn.java:305)
                                                               at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7007)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4173)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4220)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1559)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6209)
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```