# com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException: HTTP request failed, Status: 403

Tags: java, android, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, httpresponse

I have recently added fabric plugin in my android studio, but i am not finding twitter login option on that plugin. When i search on google then i found one  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44350781/how-to-install-twitter-kit-using-fabric-plugin-in-android-studio) that fabric has recently removed twitter login kit . so i integrate twitterkit using [twitter official documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/overview).
I integrate twitterkit and implement code according to [twitter developer site](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/installation), but i am facing issue.

This is the Error log:

```
E/Twitter: Failed to get app auth token
com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException: HTTP request failed, Status: 403
 at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback.onResponse(Callback.java:42)
 at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6209)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Authorization completed with an error
com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Authorize failed.
 at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.AuthHandler.handleOnActivityResult(AuthHandler.java:98)
 at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterAuthClient.onActivityResult(TwitterAuthClient.java:161)
 at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton.onActivityResult(TwitterLoginButton.java:131)
 at in.crazyfingers.cyny.social_login.ActivitySocialSignIn.onActivityResult(ActivitySocialSignIn.java:305)
 at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7007)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4173)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4220)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1559)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6209)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

I have checked [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42832290/failed-to-get-app-auth-token-twitterapiexception-http-request-failed-status-4) and [Question 2](https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitter-failed-to-get-app-auth-token-com-twitter-sdk-android-core-twitterapiexception-http-request-failed-status-403/72544/3) and other so many question which is related to this issue but its not worked for me. Help would be appreciate. Thanks in advance.

This is my app level **build.gradle** file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.twitter"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // Include all the Twitter APIs
    compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.0.0'

}
```

This is my **CustomApplication.Java** file.

```
public class CustomApplication extends Application
{
    public void onCreate() {
        Twitter.initialize(this);
    }
}
```

This is my **TwitterLogin.java** file

```
public class TwitterLogin extends AppCompatActivity
{
    public static final String TAG = "[TwitterLogin]";

    private String TWITTER_KEY = "here my app twitter key";
    private String TWITTER_SECRET = "here my app secret key";

    private TwitterLoginButton loginButton;
    private TextView status;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_twitter_login);

        TwitterConfig config = new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
                .logger(new DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))
                .twitterAuthConfig(new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET))
                .debug(true)
                .build();
        Twitter.initialize(config);

        loginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.twitter_login_button);
        loginButton.setCallback(new LoginHandler());
    }

    private class LoginHandler extends Callback<TwitterSession> {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> twitterSessionResult) {

            String output = "Status: " +
                        "Your login was successful " +
                        twitterSessionResult.data.getUserName() +
                        "nAuth Token Received: " +
                        twitterSessionResult.data.getAuthToken().token;

            Log.e(TAG, "twitterSessionResult : " + output);      
        }
        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException e) {
            status.setText("Status: Login Failed");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Pass the activity result to the login button.
        loginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: dear down voter can you please tell me why you give me down vote?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have searched in one whole day and i found the below solution. I don't know but it is worked fine for me.

I comment this line from the **Application.java** file.

```
//Twitter.initialize(this);
```

I have initialize `Twitter` SDK as below and it will work for me.

```
//Initialize twitter SDK
TwitterConfig config = new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
                .logger(new DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))
                .twitterAuthConfig(new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET))
                .debug(true)
                .build();
Twitter.initialize(config);
```

Set `callback` on twitter button as below.

```
loginButton.setCallback(new TwitterLogin.LoginHandler());
```

Comment: Perfect answer. (y)